# Why is the "else" line giving an invalid syntax error even with proper indentation and syntax?

Tags: python, if-statement

I know this question has been asked many many times on here, but I seem to not have the same issues as others. I continually get "syntax error invalid syntax else", but do not know why this is. I seem to have everything properly indented and colons after the else statement. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
def normalization (fname, attr, normType):
    result = {}
     
    df = pd.read_csv(fname)
    targ = list(df[df.columns[attr]])
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
     
    df["minmax"] = scaler.fit.transform(df[[df.columns[attr]]])
    
    df["zscore"] = ((df[[df.columns[attr]]]) - (df[[df.columns[attr.mean()]]]))/(df[[df.columns[attr.std(ddof=1)]]])
    

    if normType == "min_max":
        result = dict(zip(targ, df.minmax.values.tolist())
    
                  
    else:
        result = dict(zip(targ, df.zscore.values.tolist())
        
                                                
    return result
```

Comment: Missing closing bracket in the line before. And after.

Comment: Always look at the line above syntax errors.

Comment: `dict(zip(targ, df.minmax.values.tolist())` you missed a closing bracket

Comment: 99% of the time it's a missing bracket on the line before. Use an IDE that catches this while you're typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result = dict(zip(targ, df.minmax.values.tolist()))
```

The conversion to dictionary line in the if condition is missing one bracket.